# How to set up the SMTP settings for the ASO servers (Rails)?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, email, ssl, actionmailer

I'm trying to set up a mailer using my email, which is hosted on **A Small Orange** (asmallorange.com). I've tried the following:

- Every possible combination of settings, both with and without SSL
- searched ASO's forums
- contacted customer support

No luck so far.

**It works perfectly fine when configured for Gmail...** so the problem lies most probably in my SMTP settings.

This is the Non-SSL version of my code(in an initializer):

```
# setup_mail.rb

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
address:              'mail.mydomain.co',
port:                 26,
user_name:            ENV["EMAIL_USERNAME"]
password:             ENV["EMAIL_PASSWORD"]
authentication:       :plain, # also tried :login and :cram_md5
enable_starttls_auto: false, # tried true, too  }
```

And this is the SSL version:

```
# setup_mail.rb

ActionMailer::Base.smtp_settings = {
address:              'lagertha.asmallorange.com',
port:                 465,
user_name:            ENV["EMAIL_USERNAME"]
password:             ENV["EMAIL_PASSWORD"]
authentication:       :plain, # also tried :login and :cram_md5
enable_starttls_auto: false, # tried true, too  }
```

Any help deeply appreciated!